# Using CSS to make a liquid grid of uniformly sized divs with margins

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, liquid-layout

How would you make a liquid grid of elements with uniform size and margins in CSS?

The main problem I have is the margins. I feel that the obvious solution is to set the widths and margins to a percentage and be done with it. This doesn't work because the vertical margin is a percentage of the container's width. When the container resizes horizontally, the vertical spacing is off.

I have tried two methods. One with [percentage margins](http://jsfiddle.net/9jGYK/2/) and [one with 'em' margins](http://jsfiddle.net/9jGYK/0/). Neither of them scale correctly. What can I do?

Comment: What's wrong with your first solution?

Comment: If you resize the whole thing horizontally, the vertical margins change as well. This makes them overflow or not fill the container.

Comment: What is a liquid grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution. I wrapped each button in a container element. The outer container fits perfectly with percentages for width and height. Then, the inner element has a margin to add spacing between each button.

http://jsfiddle.net/9jGYK/4/

The margins are still dependent on the width of the body but at least the buttons are the correct size. Is there a more elegant solution out there?

Comment: It looks like the vertical and horizontal margins are the same in Gecko, but not in WebKit. I'll probably use 'em' margins instead of percentages.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LMJTu/

On the fiddle, click the button to change the size of the outer div.

Comment: I wish. I need the child elements to fill the whole container and stay in their same arrangement. When resizing the container, the children should resize to fill it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have the left and right ones having no padding or margins? (so the space in between them should be determined by the width.